# Problem with combo component

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have class representive a country

COUNTRY CLASS

```
public class Country {
 private String countryCode;
 private String countryDescription;

public void setCountryDescription(String countryDescription) {
        this.countryDescription = countryDescription;
    }

    public String getCountryDescription() {
        return countryDescription;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }
}
```

Object User have a field Country

```
public class User {
...

    private Country country;

...
}
```

In my controller:

```
public ModelAndView showUser() {
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
List<Country> list = new ArrayList();
list = dao.getCountryList(); // codes: 'DE', 'EN', 'JA' ...
mav.getModel.put("countries", list);
User u =-new User();
return mav;
}
```

In my JSP

```
<td><form:label path="country">
    <spring:message code="label.country" />
    </form:label></td>
<td><form:select path="country">
    <form:option value="0" label="..." />
    <form:options items="${countries}"  itemValue="countryCode" itemLabel="countryDescription" />
    </form:select></td>
<td><form:errors path="country" cssClass="error" /></td>
```

My message properties

messages_en.properties

```
EN=English
JP=Japan
DE=Germany
```

messages_de.properties

```
EN=Englisch
JP=Japan
DE=Deutschland
```

How to write a combo that showed the country the right to language? Can I use somthing like that `<spring:message code="label.countryCode" /`>??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<form:options>` tags, I don't think you are able to display the right language from the properties file. The workaround is to create the `<option>` tag yourself:-

```
<form:select path="country">
    <form:option value="0" label="..." />

    <c:forEach var="country" items="${countries}">
        <option value="${country.countryCode}"><spring:message code="${country.countryCode}" /></option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

Keep in mind that if you use this approach, then you are not using the `countryDescription` property from the `Country` class because the country description comes directly from the properties file.